# Python range() giving the wrong list

Tags: python, loops

I am using this little code to generate a weighted modulo-103 checksum.
The problem is that when I run the following code:

```
def checksum_bar(array):
   s = array[0]
   s += array[1]
   for x in range(2, len(array)):
       print x
       s += array[x] * x
   m = s % 103
```

I get the following result for x when entering a array of length 10:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But when I run the following code (3rd line commented):

```
def checksum_bar(array):
    s = array[0]
    #s += array[1]
    for x in range(2, len(array)):
        print x
        s += array[x] * x
    m = s % 103
```

It gives me the result I want, even though I didn't change the iteration:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Am I missing something here? I would like to know if someone can reproduce the same result and some explanation would be very nice too.

Comment: This is not reproducible with the code you've shown. Both instances should print the numbers 2 to 9. The question is unanswerable without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not getting the same results as you. Are you using python 3?

Comment: I'm using python 2. I am trying to create a minimum code in a new file but it seems to work. I will keep trying because the error persists in the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The two sets of code provided will give the same result, because the range function is sure to start from 2